# Induced subgraph; existence of path between two nodes

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, graph-algorithm, subgraph

Sorry for the wall of text, its as concise as I could make it!

I've got one very large directed graph, G, and subset of vertices, S, from within G.  What I want to do is find the subgraph of G induced by S, with the additional consideration that if some path exists between a vertex p and a vertex q in G, that an edge exists between these two vertices in the induced subgraph.  This is key; its a little more complicated (I think) than the usual induced subgraph problem.

The most rudimentary way I can think of to solve the problem is the following (I realize its probably not the most efficient, let me know if you have other suggestions that aren't *too* complicated to implement): For every pair of vertices within S, test for the existence of a path between them in G.  If such a path exists, insert an edge between p and q in the induced subgraph.  For my purposes, an n^2 time isn't *that* bad.

So, I suppose I have two questions:
1) What is the fastest way to determine whether or not a path EXISTS between two vertices?  I don't need to know the path, just whether or not it exists.  Furthermore, if there is some preprocessing I can do to the whole graph to make this calculation faster, what might it be, since I have to perform this calculation between each pair of vertices?

2) Is there a faster way than the one I suggested to find the type of induced subgraph I described?

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem of finding whether a path exists between two vertices is called the transitive closure problem, and it's as hard as matrix multiplication in the general case.  I would first run a strongly connected components algorithm on your graph to compress cycles into a single node and form a directed graph.  If you are lucky, you'll have some big cycles and that will make the subsequent transitive problem easy.  Then I'd run the Floyd Warshall all pairs shortest paths algorithm on that graph to compute the transitive closure because it's incredibly simple to code.  Maybe one of the o(n^3) matrix multiplication based algorithm will be faster, but I doubt it will be that much faster because the constant is so low Floyd Warhsall.

Here is a fast algorithm for [strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm).

And this contains a proof of the equivalence of [matrix multiplication and transitive closure.](http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs466/Old_courses/F08/transitiveClosure.pdf)

I am not sure if there is any good way to get around computing the transitive closure to solve your original problem.  I suspect not, but on the other hand, sometimes clever people come up with something great.